# TFS 2010 Get Latest Resolve Conflicts

Tags: .net, tfs

I'm currently using TFS 2010 for source control, but I'm having some weird issue.

What happens is say Developer 1 checks out some files, makes some modifications and then checks them in.  Then when Developer 2 does a 'Get Latest' on those files in Source Control it will open up the Resolve Conflicts tab and every single file that Developer 1 modified will be on there with Conflict Type: "Existing File" and Description: "A file by the same name exists locally".  I should also mention that Developer 2 has no files checked out, so I would assume that no conflicts would occur and it would just get latest on all the files.

This happens every single time someone makes a change.  Has anyone else run into an issue like this, and if so how did you fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the workspace for Developer 2 has gotten in a bad state. Can you reproduce this if you create a new workspace for Developer 2, populate it via Get Latest and then try your steps again?

Comment: Yeah, like Taylor said I use the "nuclear" option.  And just delete all files on Dev 2 computer, then do a Get Specific version to force a re-download of everything.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this recently using VS2012 & TFS2012.  We'd recently upgraded TFS, so I assume that was when/how my workspace got screwed up.

Can confirm that the TFS workspace nuke-it-from-orbit procedure fixed it for me:

1. Manually delete all files on the development machine under the problematic project that can be deleted manually
2. Right-click on the project and Get Specific Version (VS2012 moved this to Advanced > Get Specific Version)
3. Make sure both Overwrite check-boxes are checked

Some of that is clearly unnecessary, but it's a bit of feel-better voodoo.